# No network access on Ubuntu but works fine on Win10

Tags: 16.04, networking, wireless, network-manager, ethernet

I am installing Ubuntu desktop 16.04 for dual boot. On Win10, the ethernet and Wifi adapter are working well.

On Ubuntu 16.04, the machine keeps disconnected using either ethernet and wifi adapter. I have tried `ifdown && ifup` and `systemctl restart NetworkManager.service`, as well as checked with `lsusb` and `lspci`. Everything seems installed properly. Tried to restart router, but still same.

Answer (score 0):

It seems caused by the WOL configuration on Windows because the network works as normal if the Windows is completely shutdown but as mentioned when hibernating.

Just disable the option `Allow this device to wake the computer` of the network adapter on `Device manager`.

Hope this helps.